# Can I ask question about storage technical question on Unix & Linux?

Tags: discussion

When I install the Ceph in the CentOS7.2, I get a error:

```
  ......
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: 1:ceph-base-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: liblttng-ust.so.0()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:ceph-radosgw-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: libfcgi.so.0()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:ceph-mon-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: libleveldb.so.1()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:ceph-common-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: libbabeltrace-ctf.so.1()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:librados2-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: liblttng-ust.so.0()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:ceph-osd-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: libleveldb.so.1()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:librgw2-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: libfcgi.so.0()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:ceph-common-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: libbabeltrace.so.1()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 1:librbd1-10.2.9-0.el7.x86_64 (Ceph)
               Requires: liblttng-ust.so.0()(64bit)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But I don't know if I can ask this type question on Unix&Linux, because the ceph tag count only `9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why not. You are running a tool on a *nix system and having trouble with it. That seems perfectly on topic to me.

Go for it.